# Multiple nodejs apps on one VM

Tags: node.js, nginx, google-cloud-platform

Hi all that's my problem.

I have 3 nodejs apps on my domain:
 1. first.mydomain.com
 2. second.mydomain.com
 3. third.mydomain.com

Now I'm hosting those 3 apps into 3 separate VM on Google cloud platform

All those apps have their own servers, with their own routers, their workers, ecc...ecc...
Now there is a system or a tutorial for running those 3 apps into a single VM.
I was trying with nginx but I can't understand if I can use the app server or I'm forced to use the nginx server

I hope to explain my self.
Thanks

Comment: Dosn't the tutorial explain it? I would start my 3 nodejs apps on different ports and then let nginx proxy.

Comment: HI @RolandStarke can you please send me the link to the tutorial. Because I see only one tutorial to host a site with classic  html, css and js

Comment: i think this tutorial is a good start: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04, but in your case you would not use the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` configuration file, but instead have seperate configs for each app, e.g. `/etc/nginx/sites-available/app1.com`, `/etc/nginx/sites-available/app2.com`

Comment: Many thanks, after a whole day of trying and testing I did it. Now my problem is with SSL protocols...I have a lot of study in the coming days.

Comment: Hey, great to hear :)